# How to upgrade Administrate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 app with Thoughtbot Administrate for the admin part.

Recently I tried to upgrade from version 0.1.2 to 0.1.4, but I got this error: `cannot load such file -- administrate/fields/base`.

It was triggered from a custom field file, so I tried to run `rails g administrate:install`, which asked me to overwrite all my administrate controllers and dashboards.

Now, I have made customizations to those files, so I opted not to overwrite them, but then I ended up with the same error as before.

Next, I made another branch to test and let administrate to overwrite my controllers and dashboards, and this time it worked!

So, I think the question is, what is the process to upgrade the gem without losing my customizations?

Is there any task I can run in order to "register" the updated gem, like `rake administrate:upgrade` or so?

Thanks!

Comment: HI, can you please share how did you upgrade, what steps you followed. I am facing a similar issue and unable to access admin after upgrade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out the error.

Seems that `administrate/fields/base` is now `administrate/field/base`, so this subtle update in the Administrate gem code is breaking my custom field.

Anyway, I think a potentially breaking update to the gem's code should be advertised and maybe even change the mayor version number, so I'll rise an issue in github for this one.

Comment: You saved me some time. Thanks!